# How many head-choppings does Hercules have to perform to kill the Hydra in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am pretty new to Haskell. I have been struggling with for very long and have tried everything I can think of. What I want the function to do is to check the first nonzero element, decrement it by 1, and increment the next element by it's position in the list (the last element starts at position 1). For example:

Example 1:

```
[9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] -> [8,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] increments the next element by 8 since it's at position 8
```

Example 2:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1] -> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2] increments the next element by 1 since it's at position 1
```

Example 3:

```
[0,0,3,2,0,0,0,0,0] -> [0,0,2,8,0,0,0,0,0] increments the next element by 6 since it's at position 6
```

My code works for all of the cases above except where the case where the last element is nonzero. For example:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5] should return [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4] but it gives me the error 'empty list.'
```

I know I need to have a condition that checks to see if the length of my list is 1 and if it is, it should only decrement the current element by one (and not increment the next element since there isn't one). I'm just not sure how to do that. This is my code so far:

```
chop :: [Int] -> [Int]
chop [] = []
chop (x:xs) =
    if x > 0
    then [x-1] ++ [head xs + length xs] ++ drop 1 xs
    else [x] ++ chop xs
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One straightforward way would be to add a third pattern:

```
chop [] = []
chop [x] = -- TODO
chop (x:xs) = -- as before
```

If you do this, you might consider making your third pattern match on both of the first elements:

```
chop [] = []
chop [x] = -- TODO
chop (x:x':xs) =
    if x > 0
    then [x-1] ++ [x' + length xs + 1] ++ xs
    else [x] ++ chop (x':xs)
```

Another would be to make the code for your `x:xs` pattern work even when `xs` is empty, using `take 1` instead of `head`:

```
chop (x:xs) =
    if x > 0
    then [x-1] ++ map (length xs+) (take 1 xs) ++ drop 1 xs
    else [x] ++ chop xs
```

By the way, idiomatically, people typically write `foo:bar` instead of `[foo] ++ bar` whenever possible (with a few exceptions):

```
chop (x:xs) =
    if x > 0
    then x-1 : head xs + length xs : drop 1 xs
    else x : chop xs
```